# Sign extension on literal vs. variable

Tags: c++, bit-shift

I'm working with gcc 4.4.5, and have some difficulties in understanding the right shift operator on plain simple unsigned values...

This test

```
    ASSERT_EQ( 0u, (unsigned long)(0xffffffff) >> (4*8) );
```

passes.

This test

```
    unsigned long address = 0xffffffff;
    ASSERT_EQ( 0u, address >> (4*8) );
```

fails:

```
Value of: address >> (4*8)
   Actual: 4294967295
   Expected: 0u
```

It seems that the variable is treated like a signed value, and thus results in sign-extension.  (0xffffffff is 4294967295 in decimal).
Can anyone spot the difference?

Comment: What's `ASSERT_EQ`? It could be making promotions or some other nastiness. http://ideone.com/WxyUc

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: It's from the google gtest framework.

Comment: The cast-to-unsigned and right-shift both happen before being passed into `ASSERT_EQ`, but I suppose it could be defined as `ASSERT_EQ(x) foo((int)x)` or equivalent...

Comment: Depending on optimization level, one possible difference is that `(unsigned long)(0xffffffff) >> (4*8)` has been evaluated to 0 by the compiler as a compile-time constant expression, whereas `address >> (4*8)` has been translated differently, perhaps on the basis of a rule that amounts to `x >> y` -> `x >> (y & 0x1F)` (I've seen that effect before, can't remember where, to do with a shift instruction with a 5 bit immediate operand), or perhaps via a couple of steps its UB-ness has resulted in it being removed entirely. Either way it would have no effect, leaving the actual value 4294967295.

Comment: My point being, no need for it to have been bizarrely sign-extended, it just needs to have failed to shift.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is undefined behaviour to shift a value greater than or equal the size in bits of the left operand (§5.8¶1). (I assume `unsigned long` is 32 bits from your comments about 0xfffffff being the expected result if you consider sign extension.)

Still, there's probably something that `ASSERT_EQ` does that causes the difference, as it works fine on GCC 4.5 [with good old `assert`](http://ideone.com/G3rOm).

Comment: tx!  I just came to that conclusion.  And... the compiler warned me for it.  A mea culpa is in place :)

Comment: "The behavior is undeﬁned if the right operand is negative, or greater than or equal to the length in bits of the promoted left operand" wow, that's a shock! I don't see any good reason for that -- raw machine instructions define over-shifts perfectly well.

Comment: @spraff: as usual, there's probably some architecture out there that don't define these shifts...

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: And other processors that define them differently.  Leaving such shifts undefined allows compilers to just use the raw shift instructions without having to generate special-case code *just in case* the right operand is something strange.

Answer (score 3):

I think that this is all down to undefined behaviour. I believe that in bitwise shifts the results are undefined if the right operand is greater than or equal to the number of bits in the left operand.

Answer (score 2):

If `unsigned long` is 32 bits, then the behavior of shifting it by 32 bits is undefined.  Quoting the C++ 2003 standard:

> The behavior is undefined if the right operand is negative, or greater
>   than or equal to the length in bits of the promoted left operand.

Apparently the compile-time and run-time evaluations are done differently -- which is perfectly valid as long as they yield the same results in cases where it's defined.

(If `unsigned long` is wider than 32 bits on your system, this doesn't apply.)

Answer (score 0):

Both those tests [pass on gcc-4.3.4](http://ideone.com/7Q1SZ) with plain old `assert`.

Comment: and does gcc-4.3.4 give a warning too?

Comment: Yes, see "compilation info" in the link.